# I keep getting ,[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... , how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, nodemon

**mainapp.js**

```
const PORT = 3000
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const app = express()

app.length(PORT, ()=>console.log('Server running on port ${PORT}'))
```

**package.Json**

```
{
"name": "main-test-api",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "mainapp.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon index.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

After running the code this is what i get:

**output**

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..

Answer (score 2):

make change **const axios = require('axious')**
to **const axios = require('axios')**
its a typo error

Comment: I didnt see that, thanks. It's typed correctly on my code editor but i am still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace length => listen

```
app.listen(PORT, ()=>console.log('Server running on port ${PORT}'))
```

Package name is wrong

```
const axios = require('axios')
```